# A div first child goes up and get hidden by md-toolbar when the div's layout-align="center center"

Tags: angular-material

I have written the code in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ojQjOARTFuiCOjUJbE8w).

the md-toolbar and the div code portion is the following :

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill>
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <p><strong>ngClassifieds</strong></p>
            <md-button ng-click="openSidebar();">
                <md-icon class="mdi mdi-plus-circle"></md-icon>
                New classifieds
            </md-button>
            <md-button ng-init="showFilters = false" ng-click="showFilters = !showFilters">
                <md-icon class="mdi mdi-magnify"></md-icon>
                Filters
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div layout-margin class="filters" style="background-color: grey" layout="row" layout-align="center center" ng-show="showFilters">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Enter Search Term</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="classifiedsFilter">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Categories</label>
            <md-select ng-model="categoryfilt">
                <md-option ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-value="cat">
                    {{cat}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button md-no-ink style="font-weight: bold;" class="md-warn" ng-click="classifiedsFilter = ''; categoryfilt = ''; ">Clear</md-button>
    </div></div>
```

as you can see in the plunker, the first div child (an `md-input-container`) jumps up out of it and get hidden by the md-toolbar but when i changed the div `layout-align from "center center"`  to `layout-align="center"` everything was alright but why it happens ? i took this code example from a tutorial and the div layout-align value was supposed to be set to `"center center"`. Other div children don't have the same behaviour as their elder naughty sibling.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Could you explain what is the problem with your markup in this CodePen - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QKYvpR?

Comment: When the FILTER button is clicked, an input labeled "Enter search item" is shown side to side to the Categories list and the CLEAR button. The problem is that the input at the left is positionned more higher than the other elements and when it's focused its label goes under the toolbar and it get hidden by it.

Comment: you can see that behaviour on the plunker not on codepen but in the codepen too the input isn't horizontally aligned with the other elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the first example from the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select) in CodePen you will see that `layout-align=center center` causes the problem - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/yakXzX

Your markup with `layout-align=center` works fine (as you point out in your question) - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QKYvpR?editors=1010#0)

The reason for this is that the second `center` aligns all the elements horizontally in the center of the parent `div` **but** because the height of the `md-select` is different to the height of `input` the elements don't look aligned. Without the second `center` the elements are aligned at the **top** of the parent `div` and this makes them look aligned.

[image]

[image]